# .Net XmlSerializer Output Data Type

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

I have a method which takes an object and turns it into a string of XML.  This works great but I want the output XML to include the data type of object properties (string, int, double, etc).  I've searched high and low but I can't seem to find a solution without writing a custom serializer.

Any help would be most appreciated.

```
private static string ToXML<t>(t obj, bool indent = false)
{
    System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializerNamespaces();
    XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(t));
    StringBuilder sbuilder = new StringBuilder();
    var xmlws = new System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings() {OmitXmlDeclaration = true, Indent = indent};

    ns.Add(string.Empty, string.Empty);

    using (var writer = System.Xml.XmlWriter.Create(sbuilder, xmlws))
    {
        xs.Serialize(writer, obj, ns);
    }

    string result = sbuilder.ToString();

    ns = null;
    xs = null;
    sbuilder = null;
    xmlws = null;

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Also, a style suggestion - use uppercase letters, or identifiers which start with an uppercase letter, to represent type parameters to generics. This is the recommended practice by Microsoft for good reason; at a glance, readers of your code know that 'T' is the type parameter passed into your method, as opposed to an object itself.

Comment: btw, in C# you don't need to assign your locals to `null`....

Answer (score 1):

The `XmlSerializer` in .NET is designed to work with itself to re-serialize using the concrete object type to determine how it should treat the data from XML.

The standard `XmlSerializer` will not serialize that information for you.

You should look into the `DataContractSerializer` from WCF, from what I remember it's much more verbose and assumes less. It's also very flexible.